# is ready made vmware images good for python website development

Tags: python, vmware

I tried a lot and was not able to set python with django and wastd full day.

I just found this

http://bitnami.org/stack/djangostack

Is that good for development and alos does it has mod_wsgi enabled on apache.

I want to make sure that , everything is ok , so that i can start building app on this

IF there are any other alternatives

Comment: It's about development environment. Last time I checked, that's well within the realm of "programming related".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://www.instantdjango.com is a good click-and-go dev stack for Windows users. It bundles Python which is otherwise 80% of the hassle.

I suggest you be cautious when you deploy to a server though as a Django install on Linux may differ... But that's a problem you've got some time to think about.